# How do I add an image to the end of a paragraph?

Tags: css

I'd like to add an image to the end of a paragraph of a varying width, as shown below. [image] I've searched the site without finding a solution. How can it be done?

Comment: please provide an example of the HTML and CSS you have tried.

Comment: Just add an `<img .../>` tag at the end of the text, inside the `<p>...</p>` paragraph.

Comment: Sorry for the silly question! I first put the <img> tag outside the paragraph and then tried floating it and inline-block-ing it and all sorts of complicated things but not the simple one of putting it inside the <p> tag apparently! Don't I feel like a doofus now. Sorry again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CSS [:after selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3aafter)

This [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/7CCJv/) uses the content property, but if you want to use an actual image you can use a background-image instead.

```
p:after {
    content:":)";
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: Hi Brandon, thank you very much! I never heard of the after selector, and I will definitely be checking it out. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Try this [JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Rf9JW/1/). Its simple:

```
<html>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor     incididunt ut labore et dolore 
    magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
    <span><img src="image.jpg" /></span>
  </p>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Diego, that worked beautifully, thank you! I can't believe it was so simple. Feeling a little sheepish now but also very grateful! :D Thanks again!

Comment: No problem. Feel free to ask me anything in the future. <img src="smiley.jpg" />